# 'onclick' event is only triggered once

Tags: jquery, font-awesome-5, symfony5, webpack-encore

I have a problem with javascript. I don't understand why i can't click more than once on an html element.

I'll go step by step.

### Working reproductible code

The following code is what i want to do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fa-star').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let $link = $(e.currentTarget);
        $link.toggleClass('far').toggleClass('fa');
    });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<a class="icons" href="#">
    <i class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

It work perfectly fine as a stand alone.

### Providing code producing the problem

Then i put this code inside my Symfony project and manage my js file with webpack encore.

The code below is writen into this file **ajax_call.js**

```
#./assets/js/ajax_call.js
import $ from 'jquery';

function testHello() {
    alert('Hello');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fa-star').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(e.currentTarget);
        $link.toggleClass('far').toggleClass('fa');
    });
});
```

The code below is **webpack.config.js** (you'll notice that i have add a new entrypoint for **ajax_call.js**)

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('mail', './assets/js/mail.js')
    .addEntry('article_list', './assets/js/mail.js')
    .addEntry('ajax_call', './assets/js/ajax_call.js')
    //.addEntry('page1', './assets/js/page1.js')
    //.addEntry('page2', './assets/js/page2.js')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    .enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    .autoProvidejQuery()

    .copyFiles({
        from: './assets/images',
        pattern: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|ico)$/,
        // to path is relative to the build directory
        to: 'images/[path][name].[hash:8].[ext]'
    })
// uncomment if you use API Platform Admin (composer req api-admin)
//.enableReactPreset()
//.addEntry('admin', './assets/js/admin.js')
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Then my twig template for render :

```
{% extends '_base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}HANFF - Menu{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div>
        {% trans %} Bonjour, bienvenue{% endtrans %} <span id="user_login">{{ app.user.login }}</span>
    </div>
    <a class="icons" href="#">
        <i class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('ajax_call') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Now i restart yarn, running `Ctrl+C` and then `yarn watch`.

I give **entrypoint.js** which is generated to show which file exist in my **build/** directory :

```
{
  "entrypoints": {
    "app": {
      "js": [
        "/build/runtime.js",
        "/build/vendors~ajax_call~app.js",
        "/build/vendors~app.js",
        "/build/app.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "/build/vendors~app.css",
        "/build/app.css"
      ]
    },
    "mail": {
      "js": [
        "/build/runtime.js",
        "/build/mail.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "/build/mail.css"
      ]
    },
    "article_list": {
      "js": [
        "/build/runtime.js",
        "/build/article_list.js"
      ],
      "css": [
        "/build/article_list.css"
      ]
    },
    "ajax_call": {
      "js": [
        "/build/runtime.js",
        "/build/vendors~ajax_call~app.js",
        "/build/ajax_call.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Finally i testing my code and see that i can click only one time on the star icon [image] which become [image] as the `onclick` event have been triggered.

Then if i click again, nothing happens.
I have put a `console.log()` on top of `on('click')` trigger as :

```
#./assets/js/ajax_call.js
import $ from 'jquery';

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fa-star').on('click', function (e) {
        console.log('===HERE===');
        e.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(e.currentTarget);
        $link.toggleClass('far').toggleClass('fa');
    });
});
```

The `console.log()` appears just one time (first time i click on the *star icon*) and then no more.
[image]

I have follow this [course](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore/multiple-entries)

I really can't understand why i can't do a thing this much simple !
Please if you could just give me a tip it would be great.

### Update

I come with new element. I edit my javascript as the following :

```
import $ from 'jquery';
let i = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fa-star').on('click', function (e) {
        i ++;
        console.log('===HERE=== ' + i);
        e.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(e.currentTarget);
        // $link.toggleClass('far').toggleClass('fa'); <-- Comment this line
    });
});
```

And now it work, '.fa-star' element trigger the *onclick* event each time i click on it, as it should be.

[image]

But now i don't understand why this code is a problem :

```
$link.toggleClass('far').toggleClass('fa');
```

---

Maybe part of the problem (or of the solution)

when you create a `<i></i>` element, it is automaticaly interpret as a `<svg></svg>` element in the source code of the page.

This is the generated source code on Opera browser :

```
<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-star fa-w-18" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="star" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M528.1 171.5L382 150.2 316.7 17.8c-11.7-23.6-45.6-23.9-57.4 0L194 150.2 47.9 171.5c-26.2 3.8-36.7 36.1-17.7 54.6l105.7 103-25 145.5c-4.5 26.3 23.2 46 46.4 33.7L288 439.6l130.7 68.7c23.2 12.2 50.9-7.4 46.4-33.7l-25-145.5 105.7-103c19-18.5 8.5-50.8-17.7-54.6zM388.6 312.3l23.7 138.4L288 385.4l-124.3 65.3 23.7-138.4-100.6-98 139-20.2 62.2-126 62.2 126 139 20.2-100.6 98z"></path></svg>
<!-- <i class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i have say in my question, the `<i></i>` element will be interprated as a `<svg></svg>` element which hold all the attribute for displaying the correct icon.

I think that make thing hard for jQuery Selector, as the `<svg><\svg>` element doesn't contain a class with name `far` or `fa`.

- `far` class become `svg-inline--far`
- `fa` class become `svg-inline--fa`

And then the disctinction between `far` and `fa` icons is only made by the `data-prefix="far"` attribute.

I wanna specify that this kind of thing only appear when using `fontawesome v.5` because the `*-o` outline style of the class name have been replaced with data-prefix attributes :

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/upgrading-from-version-4

> **Outline Style Icons**
>
> Similarly, all icons that had an outlined style (and usually ended with -o) now have a prefix of far and have had their -o suffix removed.

So the code i have write, and which work is the following (I have moved it into:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.favProduct').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let svg = $(e.currentTarget).children('svg');
        if(svg.data('prefix') === 'far') {
            // Using attr, as data() doesn't update DOM element
            svg.attr('data-prefix', 'fa'); 
        }else{
            svg.attr('data-prefix', 'far');
        }
        $(e.currentTarget).append(svg);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything wrong with the code. It should probably a caching issue or so.

You can test it's working by clicking 'Run code sinppet' above.

Comment: I know, as i say it is working as a standalone. It is not a cache issue, as it execute my code when I change it.