# Link OnClick attribute with function encapsulated by webpack encore

Tags: jquery, webpack-encore

### Introduction

Hello,

*(This introduction is not part of the problem but it can give a little bit of context. But you can just ignore it)*

I create a new subject because it is not fully related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63346166/onclick-event-is-only-triggered-once/63353311).

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63346166/onclick-event-is-only-triggered-once/63353311) is not working, even after trying everything that come in mind, i decide to go from sratch.

### Providing details about my goal

What i want to do is call a javascript function each time i click on a html element.
Pretty simple.

Here's how my twig template looks like

```
# templates/menu/index.html.twig
{% extends '_base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}HANFF - Menu{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div>
        {% trans %} Bonjour, bienvenue{% endtrans %} <span id="user_login">{{ app.user.login }}</span>
    </div>

    <a class="icons" href="#">
        <i class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true" onclick="testAlert('{{ app.user.login|e('js') }}')"></i>
    </a>
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('menu') }}
{% endblock %}
```

I want that when i click on the **.fa-star** element, an popup show 'Hello mr ' and the username.

[image]

### What I've tried

#### First try

I write the **testAlert** function into **menu.js** :

```
#assets/js/menu.js

function testAlert(userName){
    alert('Hello mr ' + userName);
}

module.exports = {
    testAlert
}
```

I Have add the entryPoint into webpack.config.js and re-run `yarn watch`.

But this is not working, as testAlert is not global but encapsulated into the *menu.js* as I have understand.

I got this error :
[image]

#### Second try

I edit **menu.js** and write the following code

```
# assets/js/menu.js

function testAlert(userName){
    alert('Hello mr ' + userName);
}

window.testA = testAlert;
```

`yarn watch` is still running ...

I refresh the page and test it.

It work !

But I don't really like it because using `window` JavaScript object is making a function global.
And this is all of the opposit of webpack where global variable doesn't exist anymore.
I don't know if it is a good practice to do that.
So I'm kinda confuse about what I should do to achieve my goal...

Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is to add listener on some DOM element just as :

```
<a class="icons" data-user="{{app.user.login}}" href="#">
        <i class="far fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

And then the js code would be

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('a.icons').on(
           'click',
            function (e) {
               var $a = $(this);
               alert('Hello Mr : ' + $a.data('user'));
            }
        );
    }
);
```